How to ensure the table header appear?
I use LaTeX on IEEEtran with TeXLive version 2022 for writing a table as follows.

Here is the code:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,bm}
\begin{document}



\begin{table*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Performance analysis among all methods}

    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {X[1]X[2]X[1]X[1]X[1]X[1]X[1]X[1]}, 
        hlines, vlines, 
        columns={c},
        rows={m},
        row{1}={font=\bfseries},
        }  
    \SetCell[r=2]{c}pattern   & \SetCell[r=2]{c}Parameters   & \SetCell[r=2]{c}Percentage  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Average gap from calculation & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Computational time (seconds)\\

    &&& \textbf{Method A} & \textbf{Method B} & \textbf{Method C} & MIP 1 & MIP 2 \\

    [1] & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{$p_1 \in [0-300], $ $c_1 \in [0-300]$ \\\rs}& 100\% & a & b & c & d & e\\

    [2] &  & 100\% & f & g & h & i & j\\

    [1,1] & \SetCell[r=3]{c}{$p_i \in [0-300], \forall i \in \{1,2\}$ $c_i \in [0-300], \forall i \in \{1,2\}$ \\\rs}&100\% & k & l & m & n & n2 \\

    [1,2] &   &100\% & o & p & q & r & r2\\

    [1,3] &  & 100\% & t & u & v & w  & w2 \\
    
    \textbf{Average} & - & \textbf{100\%} & \textbf{100} & \textbf{200} & \textbf{300} & \textbf{400} & \textbf{500} \\
    \end{tblr}
    \label{tab:heuristic_table_X}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}


However "Computational time (seconds)" does not appear on the table head and its columns were not merged.

What needs to be adjusted?
Thank you.

The tblr environment is defined in the tabularray package and what is the definition of the \rs command?

Your code displays  57 errors. Please fix.

You need to supply & for the "missing" entries after \SetCell{c=3} or \SetCell{c=2}. The total number of & in each row must be 7.
\SetCell[r=2]{c}pattern   & \SetCell[r=2]{c}Parameters   & \SetCell[r=2]{c}Percentage  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Average gap from calculation & & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Computational time (seconds) &\\



thank you Pieter, it works!
